# Recovering ETH after sending to wrong address

Tags: contract-development, ether, etherscan, recovery

I'm struggling to find an answer to this. I have mistakenly sent all my ETH to a smart contract (used as a redemption address only for TaaS token - 0xa6b5e8df6553969de6006edb3a87ff5226f4a115). I got a reply from the company saying that there is no way to send ETH out from this address. But I find it so crazy that there was value there prior to my transaction and that there was really nothing the owner could do to get this money.

Transaction hash is 0x720f3ab54aa2d2f7b10489bf20b86d9c62adac3a82d9652b5b26da0e58d18274

It was a genuine mistake on my end, but really hoping there is something, anything, that could help to recover it. I also wasn't able to view the code for this contract to see if it is written in a way that it doesn't allow ETH to be sent out.

Any, and all, help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The address 0xa6b... appears to be an EOA but there isn't enough information. It might be a CREATE2 wallet. If it were an EOA then it has a private key and it might be possible to retrieve the tokens with it.

Comment: man i have same problem did you return your eth? is there in way to get it back or no i hope you good thanks

Answer (score 4):

If the contract did not initially include the possibility of sending Ether from it to some address, then the funds that came to it cannot be withdrawn (in public Ethereum). The only thing you can do is revise the contract code, that it really does not provide for such an opportunity.